# Signal Peptide Prediction Using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, bioinformatics, data-science, protein-database

Can anyone please guide me on how do I predict the signal peptide from a protein sequence using machine learning technique?

Any guide, reference or tutorial would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [tools](https://www.expasy.org/resources/search/keywords:signal%20peptide) out there to predict signal peptides. I'd use them first. Most signal peptides are also annotated in the Uniprot database.

But if you decide to go further with developing this, you would first need to build a dataset of signal peptide sequences in the context of the full protein sequences. I would then train a recurrent neural network on these sequences with full protein sequence as an input and signal peptide probability as an output. This probably won't work out of the box, so you'll need to do quite a bit of tweaking.